# Is this safe from sql injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I usually use sql parameters with queries, but in this case I need to dynamically create more than just the parameters.

Could someone use injection on any of the variables? Aside from a stored procedure is there a simple way to protect against injection via code?

```
string whereClause = "WHERE " + filter.ToString() + " > " + nextStartPoint;
string orderBy = "ORDER BY " + filter.ToString() + " DESC";
```

**ex**

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP(" + numItemsToGet + ") * " +
                                 "FROM Items " +
                                  whereClause + " " +
                                  orderBy;
```

Update

filter.ToString() is the actual column name

I'm surprised the following worked (partial ex)... I also thought you have to reference a column name with sql parameters.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Count", 10);

                    string sql = "SELECT TOP(@Count) * " +
```

Comment: As far as external values directly embedded, I'm not sure. I'll follow answers

Comment: It isn't clear there which parts are user-dta, and which parts are known constants from your code, but: any values from the uses should be added as parameters. This does not require stored procedures in any way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is definitely subject to injection.  If the user controls the `filter` parameter then it's very easy for them to inject bad SQL into your statement.

The simplest way to prevent an injection attack is to use `SqlCommand` to build up your command. It's designed to help prevent such attacks and will take the appropriate steps to protect your input

Comment: I've not heard of the SqlCommand class having this capability. Are you aware of any examples of this, using SqlCommand to build a dynamic query that is also protected against SQL injection?

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice here are a couple articles.  http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2008/12/sqlcommand-parameter-and-sql-injection.html, http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx

Comment: @JaredPar I don't see how parameters help with dynamic SQL.

Comment: @todda.speot.is in order for it to work you'd need to build it up with the parameters embedded in the string, likely using a numbering scheme for the replacements, and then apply that to an `SqlCommand` instance.

Comment: Hmm...you would still have to dynamically specify the column names in the query as well, which is unsafe. I supposed the code could do it more safely by validating the `filter` variable against a set of expected values (valid column names) before constructing the query and executing it.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice yes, it's likely that the column names would need to be validated independently. But this is fairly easy as compared to validating values.  The column names can be reasonably restricted + verified to contain only letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a finite set of possible filters, you can use an approach such as this, but this is a somewhat convoluted approach. I'd recommend using other tools, such as an OR mapper.

```
SET ROWCOUNT @numItemsToGet

select  *
from Items
where
    (
        @ColumnANextStartPoint is null
        or ColumnA > @ColumnANextStartPoint
    ) and (
        @ColumnBNextStartPoint is null
        or ColumnB > @ColumnBNextStartPoint
    ) and (
        @ColumnCNextStartPoint is null
        or ColumnC > @ColumnCNextStartPoint
    )
order by
    case @ColumnANextStartPoint when null then null else ColumnA end DESC,
    case @ColumnBNextStartPoint when null then null else ColumnB end DESC,
    case @ColumnCNextStartPoint when null then null else ColumnC end DESC
```

*My apologies, this code is untested.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to prevent SQL injection is to use parametrized queries like the following example:

```
 SqlConnection someConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
 SqlCommand someCommand = new SqlCommand();
 someCommand.Connection = someConnection;

 someCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@username", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = name;
 someCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@password", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = password;
 someCommand.CommandText = "SELECT AccountNumber FROM Users " + 
    "WHERE Username=@username AND Password=@password";

 someConnection.Open();
 object accountNumber = someCommand.ExecuteScalar();
 someConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information about the nature of `filter` and its string representations to rule it out. Possibly it's 100% safe because none of its possible values can cause injection, but possibly it's 100% unsafe because it's really easy to inject through it.